# Is there a meaningful definition of a discrete valuation of a matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Assume that $R$ is a discrete valuation ring with valuation $v:R\rightarrow \mathbb{N}.$ Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$.

Is there a meaningful way to extend the valuation to the matrices $K^{n\times n}$ over $K$?

By “meaningful” I mean a map $v:K^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ such that a) $v(MN)=v(M)+v(N)$ and b) for any diagonal matrix we have $v(\mathrm{diag}(x_1,\dots,x_n))=\mathrm{diag}(v(x_1),\dots,v(x_n))$.

Comment: Your first condition implies (in characteristic $0$) that nilpotent matrices, and a fortiori products thereof, are mapped to the zero (or additively: "infinity") matrix. That's bad because $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} \cdot \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0} = diag(1,0)$ which leads to a contradiction with your second condition.

Comment: Of course on the algebra $M_n(K)$ one has the maximum norm, and its discrete valuation version, with image not in matrices but in $\mathbb Z$. That seems more natural. It is only submultiplicative, but because of the example above or more generally when there are zero divisors, multiplicativity is not something to hope for.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks Torsten, I should have given more thought before posting the question.